# HBase data load (tens of TBs)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

Use-case: Load Tera Bytes of data in HBASE tables using Phoenix from CSV files for now and will load from Hive also

Cluster setup:  Six Region Server

Question: I tried Bulk load option provided by Phoenix, the performance is 1 to 2 GB per Min processing, but I am looking for faster performance. Can you help me with some suggestion? Will Spark help in any way?

Comment: have you thought about putting the files in HDFS and bulkloading from there?

Comment: yes in files are in hdfs only